# Differences between speichern, lagern, sichern?

Tags: meaning, difference

What are the differences between speichern, lagern, sichern?

Comment: There are very  big differences. Provide some context please. VTC as _too broad_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**speichern:**
It is like saving something. For example you wrote something important in word and you want to work on it later.

```
Kannst du das Bild bitte speichern und mir senden?
```

**lagern:**
Here it is like a physical object that you stow somewhere. Like a wine in a cellar.

```
Kann ich das bei dir im Keller lagern?
```

**sichern:**
**Sichern** has many meanings. For example, a police officer who secures a territory (the word on german is now `absichern`). Or protect from a danger (`sicher machen`).

Comment: in Duden it says speichern can also mean lagern, is that correct?

Comment: @Archelt as the duden said you can use the word `speichern` as synonym for the word `lagern`.

Comment: thx so much brother

Comment: @Archelt no problem :)

Comment: No you can't you it synonymously. "Bei mir speichert Wein im Keller." is plain wrong.